# call a variable from a string

Tags: python, string, variables

I am working on a python hangman game and have my graphics based on a variable, lives, so when you have 1 lives, the corresponding picture appears. i put my graphics into definitions and want to call them from that. Here's my code so far:

```
if life== 1:
        graphics1()
 if life==2:
        graphics2()
 if life==3:
        graphics3()
 if life==4:
        graphics4()
 if life==5:
        graphics5()
 if life==6:
        graphics6()
 if life==7:
        graphics7()
 if life==8:
        graphics8()
 if life==9:
        graphics9()
 if life==10:
        graphics10()
```

and so on, so is there a command which would allow me to shorten this to one or two lines?

Comment: how much `graphics1` differs from `graphics2` ? can't you make one `graphics()` function that takes `life` as an argument ?

Comment: See the selected answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I highly discourage it, but it could be accomplished by doing:

```
globals()["graphics" + str(life)]()
```

However there's most definitely a better solution. Presuming that the contents of each `graphics*()` is similar to one another.

Answer (score 0):

Well, multiple if branches can be expressed via lookup table as

```
lt = {"1":graphics1(), "2":graphics2()}
```

and so on. 
Accès to if branch via (and provide a fallback function)

```
lt.get(life, graphics1())
```

If you want to create the dict dynamically use the dict comprehension and use the *getattr* to get the function. 
Or, as stated above, generalize the function graphics passing the "ith" param to it.